kaggle can't connect to local Dash app running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
As the subject says I am running the cell below, it claims it’s running a webpage on 8050 but it isn’t. Anyone know how to fix this please?
`Linux deepthought 5.15.0-122-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 29 13:45:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

running code below in a kaggle notebook on linux mint ( ufw disabled) vpn turned off ( just in case),
it says it’s running but there’s no output from lsof -i :8050 so nothing is currently listening on port 8050.
firewall is off

sudo ufw status Status: inactive

all the iptables are open
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination     

here’s the cell from kaggle
import pandas as pd
import vizro.models as vm
import vizro.plotly.express as px
from vizro import Vizro
from vizro.tables import dash_ag_grid

# Load the data from the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/test_data.csv')

page = vm.Page(
    title="Testing vizro dash ag grid ",
    components=[
        vm.AgGrid(
            title="Test ag grid",
            figure=dash_ag_grid(
                data_frame=df
            )
        ),
    ],
    controls=[vm.Filter(column="Symbol")],
)

dashboard = vm.Dashboard(pages=[page])

Vizro().build(dashboard).run(jupyter_mode="external")

# Vizro().build(dashboard).run(jupyter_mode="tab")  # https://vizro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/user-guides/run/#jupyter

# Vizro().build(dashboard).run(debug=False)

How to Reproduce
set up a kaggle notebook
use kaggle package manager to pip install vizro
run the cell
Output
running the cell I get
Dash app running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
but either running tab or external I get
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8050.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

